# Adding IP address to my form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, ip-address

I have this php code.

```
<?php
      if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['post'])) {
             $cast = $_POST['cast'];
             $name = $_POST['name'];
             $email = $_POST['email'];
             $post = nl2br ($_POST['post']);
             $ipaddress = $_POST['ipaddress'];

if (empty($name) or empty($post)) {
             $error = 'All Fields Are Required!';
}else{
$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO comments (cast, name, email, post, ipaddress) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
     $query->bindValue(1, $cast);
     $query->bindValue(2, $name);
     $query->bindValue(3, $email);
     $query->bindValue(4, $post);
     $query->bindValue(5, $ipaddress);

     $query->execute();
?>
```

And this form.

```
<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
     <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small><br /><br />
<?php } ?>

<form action="episode.php?id=<?php echo $data['cast_id']; ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /> / <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><small style="color:#aa0000;">*</small><br /><br />
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="post" placeholder="Comment"></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
<br /><br />
<small style="color:#aa0000;">* <b>Email will not be displayed publicly</b></small><br />
</form>
```

As you can see I have set up an IP address to be saved with this form in my database.

How can I add the IP address in the form? But I do not want this to be displayed to my users.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a hidden input.  Then they would have to view source to see the IP address.

Comment: And spoof their address...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php: geting ip addres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638295/php-geting-ip-addres)

Answer (score 2):

1). You donot need to add `<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>` to the form. If case it's easy to forge it (actually it's easy any case). Better add IP to data on server side.

2) You can also look to `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`. If the user have a proxy address, some of them (transparent proxies) place real user's IP there. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` may not always contain the right address

3) Please note: The Data about IP's isn't trustworthy at all.

Comment: The user could easily spoof an ip address with this method.

Comment: Granted, you answered the question but the fact the op is asking the question in the first place would suggest they may not know the best method to do something.

Comment: Edit your answer to say this isn't actually the best way and i'll remove my downvote.

Comment: As Gavin said. I did not know any method of doing this. Which is why I asked this in the first place. Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you would replace:

> $ipaddress = $_POST['ipaddress'];

by

> $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get the ip address from the form you can get ip by php's global variable

```
 $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: Who marked this down?? I'm marking it up to restore equilibrium.

Comment: Probably someone who gave the exact same answer and didn't like competition.

Answer (score 1):

If you add ipaddress to your form then the user could change it as they wish (even if its a hidden element). You would be better getting the ip address from the request header...

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Answer (score 0):

The current Ip-address can be optained as such:

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you wan't to print it anyway? You want to save sender ip? Simply use:

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get the [IP Address](https://myipv4address.com).

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```